# Intel X86-64 assembly tutorials or book

Tags: assembly, x86-64, intel

I tried to search about intel x64 assembly tutorials with examples or a good book but I didn't find even in the intel site.

so, Could you suggest me a good tutorials or book for that ??
I'm using nasm on linux.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know about nasm tutorials, but you can get the [Intel Software Developer Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html), which you should find pretty helpful.

Comment: A tutorial at intel.com? This sounds like a poor joke. Start with [Paul Carter's tutorial](http://www.drpaulcarter.com/pcasm/). Surprisingly, it's based on NASM. When you master 32-bit assembly, switch to 64.

Comment: I recommend Introduction to 64 Bit Intel Assembly Language Programming for Linux by Ray Seyfarth. The book uses YASM instead of NASM, but YASM accepts AFAIK almost all NASM code and supports also DWARF2 debugging data format etc. The book has some SSE and AVX code too, and it assumes only some programming background and explains even binary and hexadecimal numbers etc. I have learned x86 assembly back in DOS days, but the book serves as a useful reference on how things are done in Linux x86-64 assembly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Admittedly it's personal bias how you *prefer* to learn about programming.

But with respect to assembly languages in particular, I found an approach which to me has been more useful than reading instruction set reference manuals and/or books on assembly language (where they exist).

What I normally do to figure out how assembly works for a new CPU / a CPU unknown to me on an OS platform I've not worked with yet is to leverage the developer toolchain. Like that:

- install yourself a (cross-)compiler and disassembler for the target CPU. These days, GNU gcc's / binutils ubiquity often mean that's `gcc` and `objdump -d`.
- create a bunch of small programs / small pieces of sourcecode, like:

```
extern int funcA(int arg);
extern int funcB(int arg1, int arg2);
extern int funcC(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3);
extern int funcD(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4);
extern int funcE(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4);
extern int funcF(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4, int arg5);
extern int funcG(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4, int arg5, int arg6);
extern int funcH(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4, int arg5, int arg6,
                 int arg7);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("sum of all funcs: %d\n",
        funcA(1) + funcB(2, 3) + funcC(4, 5, 6) + funcD(7, 8, 9, 10) +
        funcE(11, 12, 13, 14, 15) + funcF(16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21) +
        funcG(22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28) + funcH(29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35));
    return 12345;
}
```

- compile these *with compiler optimization* and disassemble the generated object code.
  The structure of the code is simple enough to demonstrate how the *ABI* behaves wrt. to *function calling*, *passing arguments* and *returning values*, *managing the register space* wrt. to which registers are preserved / volatile when making function calls. It'll also show you some basic assembly code for initializing constant data, and "glue" like stack access and management.
- extend this for simple C language constructs like loops and `if`/`else` or `switch` statements. Always keep some calls to external undefined functions in because doing so will prevent the compiler optimizer from throwing all your "test code" out, and when you use `if()` tests of `switch()`, predicate on `argc` (or other function arguments) because the compiler cannot predict that either (and hence optimize the building blocks of the code "weirdly").
- extend this for using `struct {}` and `class {}` definitions containing sequences of different primitive data types, in order to find out how the compiler arranges these in memory, which assembly instructions are used to access bytes/words/ints/longs/floats etc.
  All these pieces of test code you can deliberately vary (like, use different operations than `+`), and/or make more complex in order to learn more about specific pieces of the instruction set and ABI.

After you've done that, and looked at the output, locate a copy (electronic or not) of the *Platform ABI*. That contains the rulebook for how the above is done / why it is done that way, and it'll help you get a feeling for why these rules apply to the specific platform. It's essential to get an idea about the above because when you write your own assembly code, you'll have to interface that with other non-assembly (unless for pure demos). That's where you need to play by the rules, so even if you don't know them by heart, at least know where the rulebook is.

Only after that would I suggest you actually track down the instruction set reference for the specific platform.

That's because when you've gone through the above first, then you already got enough experience / you've already seen enough to  start with a small C program, compile it down to assembly source, modify that a little, assemble and link it and see if your modification does what it's supposed to do.

Attempting to, at that stage, to use some more uncommon / specialized instructions will be much easier because you've already seen how function calling works, what sort of glue code is necessary to interface your assembly with other parts of the program, you've already used the toolchain, so you don't need to start completely from scratch anymore.

I.e., to sum this all up, my suggestion is to learn assembly from *the top down* instead of *from the bottom up*.

**Side note:**

Why am I suggesting to use *compiler optimization* when analyzing compiler-generated assembly code for such simple examples ?
Well, the answer to that is because, counterintuitively to some, the generated assembly code is *much simpler* if you let the compiler optimize the hell out of things. Without optimization, compilers often create "stupid" code that e.g. puts all variables into the stack, saves and restores them from there for no reason you can see, does register saves/restores/initializations just to overwrite that reg the very next instruction and many more such things. The amount of code emitted is much much larger because of this. It's peppered with cruft and much harder to understand. The compiler optimization forces trimming this cruft down to the essential, which is what you want to see in order to understand the platform ABI, and the assemnbly. Therefore, use compiler optimization.

Comment: This is an extremely good idead/answer. Thanks very much.

Comment: This is one of the best answers I have ever seen on SO.